@react-native/assets-registry@0.75.2: The engine "node" is incompatible with this module
I ran expo install and got the below error
error @react-native/assets-registry@0.75.2: The engine "node" is incompatible with this module. Expected version ">=18". Got "16.18.0"
error Found incompatible module.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install for documentation about this command.
yarnpkg exited with non-zero code: 1

I have deleted node_modules and ran npm install still did not resolve the error.

Adding more details would make it easier to solving the problem, but from the error it says you're node version 16.18.0 but the module requires node version 18 or greater, kindly update your node and try again.
If you're using nvm:
nvm install 18
nvm use 18
npm install

If not go to Node.js download site and select v18.x.x(LTS), install and try again.
